# How can I translate only one object of the scene in an OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, translate

I have a wall pattern `DrawWall` and an airplane `DrawAirplane` in my OpenGL game. How can I push and pop the current matrix and translate only the wall in the scene?

I expect the airplane to be fixed.

```
private: void DrawWall(){
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); 
    LeftWallPattern();
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    RightWallPattern();
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}

private: void DrawAirplane(){ 
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    //...
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}

public: void Display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glTranslatef(0, -0.02, 0);
    DrawWall();
    DrawAirplane();
    glFlush();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `glPushMatrix()` to push the current matrix, do `glTranslate` and draw the wall, then `glPopMatrix()` and draw the plane. This should only translate the wall. The problem is you seem to be doing the translate in display instead of in `DrawWall` where it should be.

Comment: I changed but not affect! here is the source: http://hallaji.com/airplane/Environment.h http://hallaji.com/airplane/Main.cpp

Comment: @Hallaji I don't see anything wrong with that code (from a first glance). Do you ever call `glLoadIdentity()` to make sure you have the identity matrix loaded before the draw?

Comment: No, I didn't call `glLoadIdentity()` any where... :( Oh, What is the problem? :(

Comment: @Hallaji Yeah you should always start with the identity matrix as your current matrix.

Comment: Thank you for reply. can you please explain where should I add `glLoadIdentity()`?

Comment: @Hallaji At the beginning of display

Answer (score 1):

A few things to expand on what Jesus was saying.

When drawing the airplane you don't want to apply any transformations to it, so you need to have the identity matrix loaded:

```
Push the current modelview matrix
Load the identity matrix <=== this is the step you're missing
Draw the airplane
Pop the modelview matrix
```

When drawing the wall you **want** the current transformations to apply, so you **do not** push the current matrix or else you've wiped out all of the translations you've built up.

```
Remove the Push/Pop operations from DrawWall()
```

At some point in your initialization, before `Display` is called for the first time, you need to set the modelview matrix to the identity matrix. For each subsequent call to `Display`, -0.02 will then be added to your translation in the y-direction.